# Camel Bindy CSV unmarshal multiple files to multiple POJO

Tags: apache-camel, bindy

I have 3 camel routes parsing 3 different ~ separated files. i am using Camel bindy to parse the file to a Java Object. i Have something like below

```
<route>
<from uri ="endpoint1" />
<unmarshal>
    <bindy type="Csv" classType="package1.File1Data" />
</unmarshal>
<to uri="bean:process?method=processFile1Data" />
</route>
<route>
<from uri ="endpoint2" />
<unmarshal>
    <bindy type="Csv" classType="package2.File2Data" />
</unmarshal>
<to uri="bean:process?method=processFile2Data" />
</route>

<route>
<from uri ="endpoint3" />
<unmarshal>
    <bindy type="Csv" classType="package3.File3Data" />
</unmarshal>
<to uri="bean:process?method=processFile3Data" />
</route>
```

I get a parsing error if i have all 3 routes on, however if i retain one route (one bindy) at any given time it works fine.

I read somewhere that camel-bindy does not support, anybody else faced the same problem with Bindy?

Here is my dependecy:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-bindy-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: You are sure it is not because a file is sent to to the wrong POJO?

Comment: Yes i am sure on that, because if i keep one route at any given time it works well.

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: Yeah its a problem in spring boot and camel csv. Try outside spring boot, or wait for 2.18.2 release.